# How to parse the time out of this string?

Tags: javascript

I have date time strings coming back from an API Request that look like this:

`2016-01-31T04:22:34+00:00`

I'm not sure what type of format this is. Is there a native JS function or external library to parse the time out of these strings in a non military format?

For example to look like this:

`11:22 PM`

Comment: did you try it? `new Date('2016-01-31T04:22:34+00:00')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use [moment](http://momentjs.com/) library, Date returned from API is ISO-format, so you can parse directly using moment

```
var str = "2016-01-31T04:22:34+00:00";
var momObj = moment(str);
console.log(momObj.format("HH:mm A"));
```

Answer (score 2):

The above is a standard date format.

```
 2016-01-31T04:22:34+00:00
```

This breaks down to 2016-01-31 as date component followed by "T" and the time component 04:22:34 followed by the timezone +00:00.

You could use default javascript [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) or [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/) as well.

Examples using both :

```
 new Date("2016-01-31T04:22:34+00:00")
```

or

```
moment("2016-01-31T04:22:34+00:00").format("HH:mm:ss")
```

The parsing can be changed based on the format you want. You can refer to the docs for details.

Answer (score 0):

This date format is one of the standard formats as defined in [ISO 8601](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime).
The following should parse the given string and output the time in HH:mm AM/PM format.

```
var dtObj = new Date('2016-01-31T04:22:34+00:00');
var hours = dtObj.getHours();
var minutes = dtObj.getMinutes();
var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
hours = hours % 12;
hours = hours ? hours : 12; // 0 hrs is equivalent to 12 midnight
minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+ minutes : minutes; // prepend a 0 if minute is single digit
var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
console.log(strTime); // log in console
```

Thanks.